# Algorithms for average reward reinforcement learning in continuous/general state-action space

Tags: reinforcement-learning, algorithm-request, continuous-action-spaces, continuous-state-spaces, continuous-tasks

I see that discounted reward reinforcement learning has been extensively studied in the literature. However, the average reward metric receives less attention, and it looks like algorithms for this metric (R-learning, H-learning, SMART, etc.) are less than the discount metric. Could you suggest any algorithms for average reward reinforcement learning in continuous or general state-action space?

Comment: can you please add the references to the papers?